# Why assign a whole row by another dataframe resulting in NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single row dataframe d2 and another dataframe d1. When assign d2 to a row of d1, values of that row in d1 become NaN. Code:

```py
d1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]})
print(d1)
d2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[5],'b':[9]})
d1.iloc[[1]]=d2
print(d1)
```

Result:

```py
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
     a    b
0  1.0  3.0
1  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` is `index` sensitive , which mean when you do `assign` it also match the `index`, since the `index` in `d1` is `1` and in `d2` is `0` , that is why it will return `NaN`

---

Quick fix ,adding `.value` eliminate the impact of index

```
d1.iloc[[1]]=d2.values
d1
Out[155]: 
   a  b
0  1  3
1  5  9
```

---

See more detail

```
d2.index=[1]
d1.iloc[[1]]=d2
d1
Out[162]: 
   a  b
0  1  3
1  5  9
```

Or you even can just `update` it

```
d2.index=[1]
d1.update(d2)
d1
Out[167]: 
     a    b
0  1.0  3.0
1  5.0  9.0
```